# Interprocess communication using pipes

Tags: c, fork, pipe, deadlock, file-descriptor

Grandfather process should go through numbers from 3 to N-1. Send each number through pipe(filedes) to Father.
Father should check the content of the pipe and compute something for each number in there. If the result is positive, create children to further compute it. Children should write their results into pipe(filedes1) to grandfather. Grandfather should check the pipe before communicating with Father.

In a nutshell:

```
Grandfather - sends data to Father
Father sends data to Children
Children send data to Grandfather

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define N 20

int pid[N],child_no=0;

int prim(int m)
{
    int i;

    for (i=2; i<=m/2; i++)
        if (m%i==0)
            return 0;

    return 1; //prim
}

int check_multiples(int i, int filedes11);

int main()
{
    int filedes1[2], //grandpa->father
        filedes2[2], //father->child
        filedes3[2]; //child->grandpa
        //pid[N],,i=0

    if (pipe(filedes1)<0)
    {
        perror("pipe1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pipe(filedes2)<0)
    {
        perror("pipe2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pipe(filedes3)<0)
    {
        perror("pipe3");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((pid[child_no]=fork())<0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        if (pid[child_no]==0) //father
        {
            int m,v[N],j=0;

            close(filedes1[1]);

            while (read(filedes1[0],&m,sizeof(m)))
            {
                if (prim(m))
                    v[j]=m;

                child_no++;

                if ((pid[child_no]=fork())<0)
                {
                    perror("fork");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                else
                    if (pid[child_no]==0)
                    {
                        int k;

                        close(filedes3[0]);
                        for (k=2; k*m<=N; k++)
                        {
                            write(filedes3[1],&(int){k*m},sizeof(k*m));
                            write(filedes3[1], &(int){0}, sizeof(int));
                            exit(0);
                        }
                    }
            }

            int k;
            printf("Prime numbers between 3 and N-1 are: ");
            for (k=0; k<N; k++)
                printf("%d ",v[k]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else  //grandfather
        {
            int i,m,check=0;

            close(filedes3[1]);
            close(filedes1[0]);
            for (i=3; i<N; i++)
            {
                printf("Checking %d...\n",i);

                if (i!=3)
                {
                    while (read(filedes3[0],&m,sizeof(m))!=0)
                    {
                        printf("%d\n",&m);
                        if (m==0)
                            break;
                        if (i==m)
                        {
                            check=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("Finished checking %d.\n",i);
                if (check==0)
                    write(filedes1[1],&i,sizeof(i));
            }


        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `waitpid(getppid()...` is possibly the weirdest thing I've ever seen.  What do you think that does? (There are easier ways to set errno to ECHILD)

Comment: @WilliamPuesell I thought the grandfather exits before father. But that was not the case. My problem is I'm not using the pipes correctly.

Comment: You're reading `filedes3` before writing to `filedes1`. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ Per Johansson I skipped 3 since there wasn't going to be anything there, but it stops at 4, even if I wrote 6,9,12,15,18 in the pipe.

Comment: It does not write them into the pipe. Just checked. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The program is stuck at

```
            check=read(filedes1[0],&n,sizeof(n));
```

since no one is writing to `filedes1[1]`. If you comment out that line, the program runs to completion.

P.S. Please add the lines

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

to the file. `unistd.h` is needed for `pipe` and `fork`. `sys/wait.h` is needed for `waitpid`.

Comment: Yes, but commenting does not solve it. I could also start the for loop in grandfather from 4 since at 3 no grandchild has written anything. But then it stalls again at 4. I need a method in which processes are accessing the pipes in the correct order.

Comment: @TanatosDaniel, I am not seeing code that corresponds to what you are describing.

Comment: Here I'm trying to make it work only for father and grandfather. I will revise the code this afternoon.

Comment: @R Sahu Sorry I wasn't clear earlier. I thought posting a smaller piece of code will help with a faster identification of the problem. Hope I made it clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's several things wrong here, but I think your problem is the

```
            while (read(filedes3[0],&m,sizeof(m))!=0)
```

`read` will not return 0 until the file descriptor is closed. And it's never closed (it's kept open in Father even if Child exits).

What you should do instead is to add a special marker which indicates end of list and read until you get that marker. I'd suggest `0` or `-1` as the marker:

```
            while (read(filedes3[0],&m,sizeof(m))!=0) {
                if (m == 0)
                    break;
```

You'll have to remove the break inside `i == m` because you do need to read until the marker each iteration.

Add a write with 0 after the loop in Child. You should probably also call `exit` there:

```
                    ...
                    for (k=2; k*m<=N; k++)
                        write(filedes3[1],&(int){k*m}, sizeof(k*m));
                    write(filedes3[1], &(int){0}, sizeof(int));
                    exit(0);
```

On to some other things. This code doesn't actually use `filedes2`. Perhaps that's because you snipped some code. But you should really open that pipe inside of Father instead of inside Grandfather, otherwise Grandfather will keep a copy of those fds which I don't think you intended.

This line is wrong:

```
                        write(filedes3[1],k*m,sizeof(k*m));
```

The second argument to write should be a pointer, and you're giving it an integer. Your compiler should warn about this. Assuming you have a C99 compiler you can write it like this:

```
                        write(filedes3[1],&(int){k*m},sizeof(k*m));
```

It's called a compound literal which was added in C99.

This code doesn't scale very well with increasing N. You should `wait` for Child to exit. When you do, there's no reason to use an array of pids. If the idea is to launch multiple tasks in parallell the array size should be the max number of parallell tasks, not the number of total tasks.

And finally, please don't have a global called `i`. That's going to confuse pretty much everyone reading the code, probably including yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting me to do here: Add a write with 0 after the loop in Child. You should probably also call exit there.

Comment: Added the code for it in an edit... have to head off now for today.

Comment: Added your observations. It goes further now, but still stops. The idea was to launch multiple tasks in parallelI do not have a max number, but I would still like to know what you're saying next.

Comment: What's with the 0's? Also, something is wrong when the grandpa does the reading.

Comment: The 0 is the special marker for end of message, or magic number if you wish. You should probably add a define for it to mark its purpose.

Comment: The write with 0 should be outside the loop. It marks that the child has exit the loop.